# c# GroupPrincipal.GetMembers Performance Problems

Tags: c#, iis, active-directory

in our enviroment there are two AD Domains: DomainA and DomainB.
There is a one way trust from DomainB to DomainA.

We are using the following code to list all Users of an AD Group from DomainA from a Server in Domain (we are using a User from DomainA for the Principal Context):

```
using(PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DomainA", "DomainA\\user", "pwd");
{
    using (GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "DomainA\\DomainGroup"))
    { 
        var members = grp.GetMembers(true);

        foreach (Principal p in members)
        {
            string email = string.Empty;
            UserPrincipal u = p as UserPrincipal;

            if (u != null)
            {
                email = u.EmailAddress;
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(email) && !users.Contains(email))
            {
                users.Add(email);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code is executed within an IIS Webservice.

The code works quite well after a restart of the server in DomainB, but after a couple of tries the code gets extrem slow. There are about 700 Members in the AD Group. The code takes about 5-10 seconds after the restart, after some time the code takes about 2-3 Minutes!

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Best Regards
Bernhard

Comment: Are you sure that all previous calls have completly run? Maybe some previous calls are still running and making it slow. If that's the problem maybe you can prevent it by use locking in the method (so no simultaneous runs can happen). 
Edit: see baldricks answer - probably that's the problem

Comment: I'm logging all calls, so i'm sure that all older calls are finished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with

```
using (var members = grp.GetMembers(true))
{   }
```

The `GetMembers` call returns an `IDisposable`, and you're not it cleaning up.

See MS documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343993(v=vs.110).aspx).

> public class PrincipalSearchResult : IEnumerable, IEnumerable, 
>     IDisposable

Comment: Thank you for the hint, i think this solve my problem!